# PageReference getContent() does not work in the Experience Builder

Tags: community, experience-builder-page

I have the following Apex code which is executed by an LWC placed on a Customer Experience Page:

```
PageReference somePage = Page.Some_Page;
    
system.debug(somePage.getContent().toString());
```

This works as expected when I login to the Experience Site as an authenticated user. However when I open the same page in the Experience Builder using a System Administrator, I see that the PageReference getContent shows the normal Salesforce login page with the message "To access this page, you have to log in to Salesforce."

I have provided access to the VF page to the relevant profiles, and I even tried adding the VF Page as publicly available for that Experience Site, with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you accessing Experience Builder as an Administrator you are previewing the pages as a Guest User. The thing is that `Page.VfPage` tries to access `/page/VfPage` URL and from what I know you can't make it accessible for Guest Users.

Therefor when you're viewing it as System Administrator you see Login Page the same way if try to access `/page/VfPage` from Incognito window, but if you login as a Community User all works well

Comment: Thank you, that explains it, do you know any way in which getContent would work for the Experience Builder as well?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.community_designer_preview.htm&type=5
you can use Preview as Authentificated User, should help

Comment: Unfortunately, Preview As Authenticated User does not help either. There's some Builder weirdness there which we need to live with I guess.
Also it's not really true that Builder renders page as Guest User. It's just your user, judging by record and metadata access you get.

Answer (score 0):

were you able to make it work in experience builder? Previewing it as Authenticated user, wont help as in experience builder it shows an error and we are not even able to see or drag-drop in experience builder

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/173771)